# How to pass data between two Worker Services

Tags: c#, .net-core, backgroundworker, ihostedservice, worker-service

Let's say I have two long running custom services and two WorkerServices registered with host:

```
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
{
    services.AddSingleton<IServiceA, ServiceA>();
    services.AddSingleton<IServiceB, ServiceB>();

    services.AddHostedService<WorkerServiceA>();
    services.AddHostedService<WorkerServiceB>();
});
```

IServiceA is resolved and run by WorkerServiceA.

IServiceB is resolved and run by WorkerServiceB.

##### Problem:

IServiceA needs to notify/pass some data to IServiceB so it can then further process it.

How can such communication be implemented?

Comment: Search for [producer / consumer pattern](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/producer-consumer-pattern-in-c-sharp/).

Comment: Are you in the cloud or on-premises?  The simple approach would be to use one of many queue implementations.  On Windows Servers, there is a "Message Queues" component.  In the cloud, Azure Storage accounts have a queue implementation as well, but it behaves differently.  Ultimately, when A needs to communicate with B, then A should drop a message in a storage queue.  B can monitor the queue for new messages periodically and process new requests.

more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-queues-introduction

Comment: Do you want that `serviceA` will trigger some actions in `serviceB` with given data?

Comment: @PeterBons this looks like something I am looking for... @ GlennFerrie the software will run on Linux on-premises. @ Fabio yes, ServiceB will further process and act upon received data from ServiceA. Since there is a need to use patterns such as producer/consumer / queueing, does that mean that each WorkerService is a separate process? Are they not visible one to another through the host application?

Comment: @Kris they do not have to be in different processes, there are in-process options. Can you elaborate a bit more on what data is transfered and when?

Comment: @PeterBons So the ServiceA is a MQTT client background worker service running on Linux gateway meant to handle comms between field devices and gateway. Then ServiceB is a SSH Client running on another worker service on same gateway. Field device issues requests through MQTT, the MQTT Client parses the message, and if request is to connect to a yet another server to issue a SSH command or create port forwarding, the request must be passed to SSH Client  with port numbers, commands etc. I am now thinking about moving the SSH Client on the same worker service as MQTT client to simplify things.